# HTML element full width including ::before selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

So I have this example code:

```
<span class="element-class"><input type="text"></span>
```

The `.element-class` is `width:100%;`
And I have a `::before` selector with content (FontAwesome icon). But the `::before` selector's content is in separate line than the `input` element.

¿How can I do to have a 100% width element including the `::before` selector? I made a workaround using 95% width. But is not an elegant solution.

Comment: Can you post complete code...

Comment: use calc() in width. if your before width is 25px:

`.element-class{width: calc(100% - 30px);} //5px spacing between`

Comment: Give us your code and we help you

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can do that.

```css
span.element-class {
  display: flex;
}
span.element-class input {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<span class="element-class fa fa-search"><input type="text"></span>
```